# How do I fix this out-of-date SSL issue with Pow and Tunnelss?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, encryption

I'm using a local environment setup where I have two applications running using [Pow](http://pow.cx/manual.html), and one makes an API request to the other. I'm using [tunnelss](https://github.com/rchampourlier/tunnelss) for SSL.  I start up application A running at it's domain `appA.dev`, and when I check the SSL certificate on that page, I get a warning from Chrome with this error:

> Your connection to www.3rdhome.dev is encrypted using an obsolete cipher suite. Further, this page includes other resources which are not secure. These resources can be viewed by others while in transit, and can be modified by an attacker to change the look of the page.
>
> The connection uses TLS 1.0.
>
> The connection is encrypted using AES_256_CBC, with HMAC-SHA1 for message authentication and RSA as the key exchange mechanism.

Despite this, I try calling the API from `appB.dev` using the [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) gem. Here's a sample of the code:

**API Call From Service**

```
  def fetch_property
    headers = {"Authorization" => "Token token=#{@api_key}"}
    response = HTTParty.get(property_url, :query => {}, :headers => headers)
    if response.success?
      @property_data = response["property"]
      response["property"]
    else
      raise response.response
    end
  end
```

**Controller Code**

```
  begin
    property = api_service.fetch_property
  rescue StandardError => e
    redirect_to error_path, notice: e.to_s
  else
```

And I recieve the following notice:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

How can I fix this SSL issue so that I can make API requests to the server?